# Крякозябры в Powershell, pwsh при добавлении findstr

Tags: windows-10, powershell, кириллица, windows-11

Пробую вывести сообщение в консоли Windows, и для cmd, ps и pwsh получаю разные результаты (Win10/11, pwsh 7.2.0).

Как правильно вывести русский текст в PS/Core при добавлении | findstr? Без findstr кириллица отображается нормально.

**cmd (OK)**:

```
ipconfig | findstr "IPv4" | findstr "10."
   IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.169
```

**ps**:

```
ipconfig | findstr "IPv4" | findstr "10."
   IPv4-?????. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.169
```

**pwsh**:

```
ipconfig | findstr "IPv4" | findstr "10."
   IPv4-тХитЦСтХитФдтХд╨РтХитХбтХд╨С. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.169
```

Comment: `ipconfig | Select-String -Pattern "IPv4"  | Select-String -Pattern "10."`

Comment: В powershell установить кодировку консоли `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("cp866")` и будет выводить нормально

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, ваш вариант работает!

Comment: @ipatev_nn кажется ваш способ не работает в pwsh

Answer (score 0):

[Console]::OutputEncoding - занятная штука - она может поменять кодировку, а может и нет. Всё зависит от желания самого PS_ISE, если вы пользуетесь им.

Очень часто PS_ISE не меняет кодировку, когда у тебя открыто куча окон и некоторые, где-то в глубине недр PS имеют процессы, связанные с получением данных в подтверждённой источником кодировке и которая не соответствует той, которую вы желаете установить в данный момент. Не меняет, и всё тут.

В мануале сказано, что для того, чтобы PS поменял кодировку, нужен внешний пинок — получение внешних данных с подтверждённой кодировкой — это страницы интернета. Кто ещё может подтвердить кодировку — ну конечно же он, незаменимый cmd.exe, который при каждом соединении возвращает код ошибки, и то, что мы не видим — кодировку, как я помню.

Вот то, что я сделал вчера и оно вроде работает. Сегодня была небольшая проблемка — поменял код (сделал смену кодировки после пинка батника) и всё нормально пока.

```
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers
$codepage = @{'netName' = 'utf-8';'identifier' = 65001}
# $codepage = @{'netName' = 'windows-1251';'identifier' = 1251}
# $codepage = @{'netName' = 'cp866';'identifier' = 866}
try{$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($codepage.netName)}catch{} 
&C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ('/c echo off&chcp {0}>NUL&exit '-f $codepage.identifier) #просто возвращает код отсутствия ошибки 0, который и провоцирует смену консоли
#cls
if([System.Console]::OutputEncoding.WebName -ne ([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($codepage.netName)).WebName){Write-Host '"Скрипт выполняется в кодировке отличной от '([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($codepage.netName)).WebName'. Некоторые символы могут оказаться нечитаемы.'}
Write-Host 'текущая PS консоль'([System.Console]::OutputEncoding.WebName)
```